# Wireshark plugin causing causing 'heap corruption'

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I'm writing a wireshark dissector and experiencing odd memory management problems. I have the following function:

```
guint8* foo_hex2bytes(guchar *str, guint len){
    ...
    //allocate memory for the result and start converting
    res = (guint8*)wmem_alloc(scope, sizeof(guint8)*((len>>1)));
    for(i=0; i<(len>>1); i++){
        //check that the two digits under question are HEX digits
        if(!isxdigit(*(str+2*i)) || !isxdigit(*(str+2*i+1))){
            wmem_free(scope, res);
            return NULL;
        }

        //append the byte
        sscanf((const char*)(str+2*i), "%02x", &res[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This function is used in several places (`proto_reg_hanoff_foo` as well as `dissect_foo`) hence I do not allocate the result to any specific pool.

In my  `proto_reg_handoff_foo` I'm getting the return value of the function, copying it to another memory location and freeing the original result:

```
...
if(syskey_str && strlen(syskey_str)){
    wmem_free(wmem_epan_scope(), syskey_bytes);
    if(tmp = foo_hex2bytes((guchar*)syskey_str, (guint) strlen(syskey_str))){
        syskey_len = (guint)strlen(syskey_str)>>1;
        syskey_bytes = (guint8*)wmem_alloc(wmem_epan_scope(), strlen(syskey_str)>>1);
        memcpy(syskey_bytes, tmp, strlen(syskey_str)>>1);
        wmem_free(NULL, tmp);
    }
}
...
```

Oddly enough, I'm getting a windows-triggered breakpoint (or plain crash outside of debugger) at `wmem_free(NULL, tmp)` line. There is no real debug information that I'm able to gather other than the fact that error happens at [`wmem_core.c:72`](https://github.com/boundary/wireshark/blob/master/epan/wmem/wmem_core.c#L72).

N.B. I have modified my `foo_hex2bytes` to accept third `wmem_allocator_t` parameter and simply passed `wmem_epan_scope()` (or `wmem_packet_scope()` where appropriate) - this results in similar crash when the application is being closed down. I have also tried using `malloc()` and manually clearing all the memory (which sometimes works, sometimes returns `null pointer` even thought the application only uses 14K of memory and has plenty more available).

**EDIT:** The issue seems to exist in line `sscanf(...)` - I had not allocated enough memory and it was overrunning. Fixed by increasing the allocation size.

Comment: (I'd like to suggest editing the title to something like "Wireshark dissector 'heap corruption'" or something similar since the issue had nothing to do with wmem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `foo_hex2bytes` you're passing in `syskey_str`, but the length of `devkey_str` - should be the length of `syskey_str`?

The breakpoint you're getting just means that the heap has become corrupted due to writing memory beyond what was allocated.

Comment: well spotted... unfortunately that's not the issue (both syskey_str and devkey_str have the same length). The issue seems to happen when memory is being cleared (via `wmem_free(...)` either manually or at the end of application) - I really can't see why that is happening.

Comment: Scratch that, you are absolutely right in that the issue is caused by memory write access beyond allocation.